# How to set chart location in Extent Reports version 4?

Tags: extentreports

I'm trying to set the chart location in the new version of Extent Reports.

I'm no longer able to import:

```
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.configuration.ChartLocation;
```

That library no longer exists.  Which of course makes this line of code useless:

```
htmlReporter.config().setTestViewChartLocation(ChartLocation.BOTTOM);
```

I've been trying to find some better Extent documentation but can't find anything beyond version 3.  Does anyone know how to set the chart location?

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue and after doing extensive search I found out this - http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/4/java/breaking-changes.html

Just remove the ChartLocation from configuration and you should be good to go.

Comment: Seems that OP wants to set the location of the chart (find equivalent of ChartLocation), not just get rid of error message...

Comment: The default config for ChatLocation is located at -

C:\Users\<user>\.m2\repository\com\aventstack\extentreports\4.0.9\extentreports-4.0.9.jar!\html.properties


C:\Users\<user>\.m2\repository\com\aventstack\extentreports\4.0.9\extentreports-4.0.9.jar!\spark.properties

You can override the properties file while starting (start()) the extent reports.

For example :-

chartLocation=top to chartLocation=bottom

Hope this is helpful